# JSF 2.2, h:inputFile component with f:ajax

Tags: ajax, tomcat7, jsf-2.2

When I use **h:inputFile** with **f:ajax** and try to deploy it on **Apache-tomcat-7.0.8**, 
the following exception is thrown by the tomcat server when the AJAX request is sent. Can any one please help me to fix this issue. Thanks.

**javax.servlet.ServletException on Tomcat**

```
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.FileRenderer decode
SEVERE: Unable to get parts for frmIndex:file
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
```

**JSF Page**

```
<h:form id="frmIndex" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{indexController.file}"/>

   <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{indexController.postTrailDetail}">
      <f:ajax execute=":frmIndex:tUpostPanelGroup" render="@all"/>
   </h:commandButton>

</h:form>
```

**Java Controller**

```
@Component
@SessionScoped
@Scope("session")
@Qualifier("indexController")
public class IndexController implements Serializable {

  private Part file;

  public void postTrailDetail() {

   if(file != null) {} 

  }

  // Getter and Setter for Part

}
```

**Maven dependencies**

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0-m03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0-m03</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try without f:ajax tag? I have problem eith this tag and error message when use ajax. Without ajax every is fine.